# find . -exec grep -l 'string' {} \; -print 2>/dev/null

Tags: find, grep, xargs

it lists all files in "." that contain the string "string" but don't show dirs with permission denied.

What would it be the equivalent of that but squeezing xargs in between?

Comment: Why do you want xargs inbetween?

Comment: @Closers: Shell scripting is programming; this could easily be more appropriate for SO than SU (it depends on other details the OP has not yet provided).

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -readable | xargs grep -l 'string'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `grep` if it has `-R` option

```
grep -R -l "string" * 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l 'string'
```

This handles names with blanks (etc) in the file names - and assumes you are using GNU find and xargs.